# How to get the checked item id in custom list view with multiple selections in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

How to get the checked item id (custom id, not the position or name of the selected item -in my case order id i need to retrieve) in a custom list view with multiple selections in android.
I have Order name and Order id   from json and its populated in custom list view ,In the custom list view i have   text view and check box but how to get the Orderid's of  the selected/checked Orders.

I have a button when i click the  button i  need to  retrieve the id not the  name or  position , in my case  i need  order id  to be  retrieved[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved  and  got the OrderId by using below code , this worked for me and  i could retrieve the  custom ORDERID which i passed to the  list

```
                      int isSelectedOrderNumber=0;
          mOpenOrdersSelected = new ArrayList<OpenOrders>();              
                      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          Iterator<OpenOrders> it = mOpenOrders.iterator();
          while(it.hasNext())
          {
              OpenOrders objOpenOrders = it.next();
              //Do something with objOpenOrders
              if (objOpenOrders.isSelected()) {
                  isSelectedOrderNumber++;
                  mOpenOrdersSelected.add(new OpenOrders(objOpenOrders.getOrderID(),objOpenOrders.getOrderName()));
                  sb.append(objOpenOrders.getOrderID());
                  sb.append(",");
                }
             }

          //Below Condition Will Check the selected Items With parameter passed "mMAX_ORDERS_TOBEPICKED"
            if(isSelectedOrderNumber<1){
                ShowErrorDialog("Please Select atleast One order");
                return;
            }
            if(isSelectedOrderNumber>mMAX_ORDERS_TOBEPICKED){
                ShowErrorDialog(" Select Maximum of  "+mMAX_ORDERS_TOBEPICKED+ " Orders only to process");
                return;
            }
           Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "cheked Order Items: " +sb);  
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cheked Order Items id:" +sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `ListView.getCheckedItemIds()`. It will return a long[] with all checked ids.
There is also `ListView.getCheckedItemPositions()` which will give you all checked positions.

Make sure you set `ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` in `onCreate()` or whereever you set up your views (or in layout xml).

To get the checked values you just need to do this:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
    if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
        int pos = checked.keyAt(i);
        Object o = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
        // do something with your item. print it, cast it, add it to a list, whatever..
}
```

Comment: I tried but its returning some strings
tried like this:

  long[] checkedID =  mListView.getCheckedItemIds();
 //convert long to string
 String strcheckedID = String.valueOf(checkedID);

 // mListView.getCheckedItemIds();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Items:: " +  strcheckedID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: How can it return Strings, if it is defined to return a long[]?

Comment: @JerryAbraham: I really don't understand, what you are trying to do there with the Toast. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mean when i toast its  not  returning the  ids , its showing some java string values ,

How to  Toast the long[]??

I tried like this

  long[] checkedID =  mListView.getCheckedItemIds();
 //convert long to string
 String strcheckedID = String.valueOf(checkedID);

 // mListView.getCheckedItemIds();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Items:: " +  strcheckedID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I want the selected id/checked id's  to see  first off all  , then that  selected  id's i  need  to pass  to the server. So first i need  to  see the selected /checked id which is coming from the server. Inorder to see the  values of the checked i just put the toast

Comment: I really do not understand your problem, but to build a proper string of long [], you might want to do this: `long[] longs = yourListView.getCheckedItemIds(); StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); for (long l : longs) { sb.append(" ").append(l); }; String result = sb.toString().trim();`

Comment: I tried but its not toasting any id's or anything when i moved that to string by this way ,
long[] longs = mListView.getCheckedItemIds(); 
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
 for (long l : longs) { sb.append(" ").append(l); };
 String resultOfCheckedIds = sb.toString().trim();

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Items:: " +  resultOfCheckedIds, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

I want 1stof all to see  the id's of selected items when so i am  trying to toast the values of selected/checked id's
I aM NewBi 2 android ,So  plz help

Comment: are you finally happy with it?

Comment: No luck yet !! I could not find the  checked id's
let me say once more i am using a custom list view 
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
       mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
so will your solution work,  i tried in many ways now but i am not able to get the checked item id

Answer (score 0):

Jerry, set your order object as tag to the view which has selection event [CheckBox, TextView, Row view], when user select item you can get selected order object from tag and you can get any member of that object(order). for ex.

Order Object

```
Order {
int id;
String name;
boolean isSelected;

//add getters and setters
}

void getview(...) {
     View v = //inflate view
     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(..);
     cb.setTag(yourlist.get(position));
     cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
             ((Order) buttonView.getTag()).setSelected(isChecked);
        }
     });

}
```